# WordPress remove admin menu item

Tags: wordpress

Generally it's not a problem to remove wp-admin menu items, e.g:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

function my_remove_menu_pages() {               
  remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' );                                          
}
```

However I'm currently struggling with the following page:

```
admin.php?page=wpml-string-translation/menu/string-translation.php
```

What's the best method to have this one removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=wpml-string-translation/menu/string-translation.php', 'admin.php?page=wpml-string-translation/menu/string-translation.php' );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're add_action needs a numeric as a 3rd argument (a priority).

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55581/how-can-i-remove-the-wp-menu-from-the-admin-bar

#### Example

If you have this add_action:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_wp_menu', 10 );
```

To remove it, it needs a higher priority (11):

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove WP Menu From Tool Bar
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_remove_wp_menu' ) )
{
    // The action is added with a priority of 10, we take one step later.
    add_action( 'init', 't5_remove_wp_menu', 11 );

    /**
     * Remove the WP menu action.
     */
    function t5_remove_wp_menu()
    {
        is_admin_bar_showing() &&
            remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_wp_menu', 10 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answers, here's the completed solution for both WPML user menus:

```
function remove_menu_items()
{
    //removes the 'String Translation' menu item from editor's admin screen
    if (defined('WPML_ST_FOLDER')){
        remove_menu_page(WPML_ST_FOLDER.'/menu/string-translation.php');
    }
    //removes the 'Translation Interface' menu item from editor's admin screen
    if (defined('WPML_TM_FOLDER')){
        remove_menu_page(WPML_TM_FOLDER . '/menu/translations-queue.php');
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items', 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution:

```
function remove_menu_items()
{
    //removes the String Translation menu item from editor's admin screen
    if (defined('WPML_ST_FOLDER'))
        remove_menu_page(WPML_ST_FOLDER.'/menu/string-translation.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items', 999);
```

It needs a higher priority from which it was created and to avoid any issues let's use the same WPML constant, which we can find on the file "wpml-string-translation-class.php" at the plugin folder, line 212 as of version 1.6.1 of the WPML String Transtation plugin.